# "Move" up table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, line-spacing

Currently writing my thesis using LyX, I am having a bit of trouble with my Table of Contents. The TOC is so long that I have 1 line on second page, which obviously doesn't look good. Therefore, I want to either have a smaller margin above the "Content" header, or remove a little of the space between the header and the table of content text.

I am using a template that I've gotten, and therefore do not fully understand it all. In the beginning of the preable, these packages are loaded:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}           % \titleformat and \titlespacing
\usepackage{titletoc}
```

In the preable, the following makes up the TOC:

```
%%% TOC %%%
\newcommand{\showTOC}{
\cleardoublepage
\settocdepth{subsection}
\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{contents}
% Set \part formatting in TOC
\renewcommand{\cftpartname}{Part\space}
\newlength{\mylen}                      % Increase spacing after part number
\settowidth{\mylen}{\bfseries\cftpartaftersnum\space}
\addtolength{\cftpartnumwidth}{\mylen}
\renewcommand{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{\ \par}    % No page numbering for part
% Show TOC
\tableofcontents*
}
```

In my document, the table of content is simply made by:

```
\tableofcontents*
```

With a Page Break before and after.

Any ideas to how I can either move up the header or adjust the spacing under the header, such that 1 extra line fits up the first page?

Comment: Welcome, without a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html), this question is very hard to answer, as we cannot reproduce your issue. [Create a minimal LyX example](https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample)

Comment: Looking at the definition of `\showTOC` gives me goose bumps.

Comment: Maybe trying  something like `{\setstretch{0.9}\tableofcontents*}` (requires loading `setspace`)?

Comment: You can also try `\enlargethispage{1.5\baselineskip}` before digging deeper.

Comment: Appreciate the answers. Wasn't sure what to leave out, to make a minimal working example, so I tried just writing the code.

It worked using `\enlargethispage`, but it made it quite "crowded" on the buttom. I used `\vspace*{-2\baselineskip}` instead, that worked well.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: @AndersHessChristensen -- since you have come up with a working solution, you can write a "self answer", and accept it after a suitable delay.  that will keep the question off the unanswered list, and the idea may be helpful to someone else who comes along later.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Anders Hess Christensen worked great:

```
\cleardoublepage
\vspace*{-2\baselineskip}
\tableofcontents
```